# Limit number of characters in product name within a product list

Tags: php, list, magento, product

I am trying to limit the characters of a product name in the product list. I have found this code:

```
// define the maximum length of the product name here
$maxLength = 10;
$productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
echo substr($productName, 0, $maxLength);
```

In my theme I have this code:

```
 <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
```

and I change it to this:

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php $maxLength = 10;$productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
echo substr($productName, 0, $maxLength);) ?></a></h2>
```

I get a parser error. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Is it especially a matter of presentation in your list page ? If it is, you can easily solve your problem with CSS. I had the same situation with long product names and I just specify :

overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space:nowrap;

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 class="product-name">
  <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
     <?php 
        $maxLength = 10;
        $productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
        echo substr($productName, 0, $maxLength);)
     ?>                                      -----^
 </a>
</h2>
```

Should be

> echo substr($productName, 0, $maxLength);

You could also using `Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($productName, $maxLength);`

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter parse errors it is generally a good idea to start by adding line breaks and indentation to your code as it provides a much clearer overview of what you might have done wrong.

In this case an extra parenthesis as R.S's answer points out.